# IBP 2.0 - How to download crypto config fixtures and instantiate Fabric SDK?

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric

I am running a business network on IBM Blockchain Platform 2.0. When using the `fabric-sdk-go`, we need to provide a `cryptopath` which normally points to the various certificates generated using `cryptogen` for manually created networks.

However, the connection profile available for download from IBP 2.0 does not include those details, and thus the SDK is unable to instantiate due to missing parameters.

`FATA[0000] Error setting up Fabric SDK                   env=DEV error="failed to create identity manager provider: failed to initialize identity manager for organization: fftxmsp: Either a cryptopath or an embedded list of users is required"`

How can I download those fixtures? Or how can I bypass this error?

Thanks

Comment: hey did you found any solutions?